# find out a class variable's defined scope (from within the class)

Tags: php, class, reflection, phalcon

Given:

```
class myClass extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $a;
    protected $b;
    private $c;
}
```

How can I test that $a is public, $b is protected, and $c is private from within *myClass*?

Comment: And why do you need that?

Comment: @b0s3 trying to automate the fetching and displaying of data. for example if i set *created_time* as private, it wouldn't get displayed on the client form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ReflectionProperty](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.construct.php) -

```
class myClass
{
    public $a;
    protected $b;
    private $c;
}

$obj = new myClass();
$reflect_a = new ReflectionProperty(get_class($obj), 'a');
$reflect_c = new ReflectionProperty(get_class($obj), 'c');

var_dump($reflect_a->isProtected());
var_dump($reflect_c->isPrivate());
```

Depending on the result you can hide or show them.

Comment: it works outside the class but I'm having trouble calling it inside the class: i get *Property myClass::$a does not exist* - maybe because of the framework?

Comment: oops was calling the wrong class. thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

For your needs you can use use Models [Meta-Data](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-metadata.html). You can get the attributes of the model within the model:

```
<?php

/**
 * Posts Model
 *
 */
class Posts extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    public $users_id;
    public $categories_id;
    public $title;
    public $slug;
    public $content;
    public $number_views;
    public $number_replies;
    public $votes_up;
    public $votes_down;
    public $sticked;
    public $modified_at;
    public $created_at;
    public $edited_at;
    public $status;
    public $locked;
    public $deleted;
    public $accepted_answer;

    private $foo_bar;
}
```

Somewhere in the controller:

```
var_dump($this->modelsMetadata->getAttributes(new Posts()));die;
```

Output:

```
array (size=18)
  0 => string 'id' (length=2)
  1 => string 'users_id' (length=8)
  2 => string 'categories_id' (length=13)
  3 => string 'title' (length=5)
  4 => string 'slug' (length=4)
  5 => string 'content' (length=7)
  6 => string 'number_views' (length=12)
  7 => string 'number_replies' (length=14)
  8 => string 'votes_up' (length=8)
  9 => string 'votes_down' (length=10)
  10 => string 'sticked' (length=7)
  11 => string 'created_at' (length=10)
  12 => string 'modified_at' (length=11)
  13 => string 'edited_at' (length=9)
  14 => string 'status' (length=6)
  15 => string 'locked' (length=6)
  16 => string 'deleted' (length=7)
  17 => string 'accepted_answer' (length=15)
```

Also you can create an model's method:

```
public function getAttributes()
{
    $metaData = $this->getModelsMetaData();
    return $metaData->getAttributes($this);
}
```

`\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::getAttributes` Returns table attributes names -  fields of table.

Also PHP's [`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) returns an array of all properties visible in the current scope. In your case it should return all public properties.

Comment: the current Phalcon version (2.0.6) modelsMetaData does not have a method that will give the variables' scope. Also, get_class_vars() does not distinguish between public, protected and private inside the class.